# set variable in html and add into auto-redirect code

Tags: html, variables, redirect

We're working on adding a number of custom pages to our LMS solution which act as simple redirects to other areas of the system.  We have been through a few iterations of trying to get this to work (as the system only likes certain code) and we've managed to get the following to work:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){location.href="/redirect/to/newpage.html"} , 250;')
</script>
```

However, we want to make it a bit simpler for them to update (as we fear they'll break something) and want them to put the URL in a variable at the start of the code and call that in the redirect code.  We'll also use the variable to drive a "if you're not redirected within x, click here" link at the bottom.

We've tried a number of things including adding:

```
<script>
    redir = "/redirect/to/newpage.html";
</script>
```

and then calling back into the redirect code... but no matter what we try, it doesn't seem to recognise it.  The rest of the page is purely a loading image within the main LMS framework.

Help?

Comment: use `var redir = "/redirect/to/newpage.html";` as you must declare the variable.

Comment: Thanks jtheman,

I should have said - we tried that too and it didn't seem to make a difference.  It could be that we have been writing the syntax incorrectly in the 'setTimeout' section... however the ideal outcome is:

(...){location.href=redir}(...)

Comment: Yes there is a little error there, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var redir = "/redirect/to/newpage.html"; // declare variable with var
</script>
```

Then

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){location.href=redir} , 250); // fixed a little typo here
</script>
```

Comment: Worked a treat - the spurious ' and ; at the wrong bits seem to have been leftover from various attempts!  Simple case of being too close for too long!

Thanks jtheman

Comment: @Jonathon Great it helped. Please accept my answer, both you and I will be rewarded with reputation scores and the community gain from questions marked as answered.